# VBA applying conditional formatting to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to a range that checks cell X1 and if it doesn't match it applies the conditions.

If i apply it to one cell it works great. however i need it applied to each cell in a range.

code:

```
    Function FindComment(rng As Range, strSearch As String) As Boolean

On Error GoTo err_h:

strSearch = LCase(strSearch)

If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
    FindComment = False
    Exit Function
End If

If InStr(1, rng.Comment.Text, strSearch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, rng.Text, strSearch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    FindComment = False
    Exit Function
End If

FindComment = True
Exit Function

err_h:
    FindComment = True
End Function
```

And to apply the conditional formatting:

```
Public Sub AddConditionalFormat(rng As Range)

   rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=FINDCOMMENT(" & rng.Address(, , xlA1) & ",$X$1)"
    rng.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ColorIndex = 2
    End With

    With rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlGray75
        .PatternThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .ColorIndex = 2
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    rng.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

the range range("B6:GD9") are determined as rng.

currently if the results match it just blanks out all cells including the match.

anyone have an idea of how to easily fix? i'd prefer something that would not lag out the code by applying to each cell etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) defaults to absolute row and column references. You are looking for something like `A1` but you are getting `$A$1`.

```
rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=FINDCOMMENT(" & rng.Cells(1, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False, ReferenceStyle:=xlA1) & ", $X$1)"
'alternate in shorthand
rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=FINDCOMMENT(" & rng.Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0, xlA1) & ", $X$1)"
```

Using `.Cells(1, 1)` should make that formula reference the upper left cell in `rng`.

Comment: Thanks, i need it to be able to reference to active cell (i.e. if B9 is selected i need the conditional formatting to be applicable on B9 not referencing B6 which is the upper left)

Comment: this is working now but it highlights EVERYTHING in the range as white when a positive result is found not just the result. any further suggestions?

Comment: I'll have to work up a more complete workbench. It seems to me that the problem may be in your formula assignment. If you are applying that CF rule to B6:GD9, the formula should start out as `=FINDCOMMENT(B6, $X$1)` which is what I though I gave you. The CF rule adjusts it *relative to* the top-left cell in the Applies to: range. Essentially, the formula should be the same for all cells in an xlR1C1 style; e.g `=FINDCOMMENT(RC, R1C24)`. Is there any way that the FINDCOMMENT is erroring out on everything? You have it returning True on error.

Comment: it works! :) sorry mate i was stopping the code before cell comments got applied! as soon as cell comments were applied it worked fine :D thanks so much! :D saves me so much time.